# RSS Feed Sticky Post?

Tags: wordpress

My latest RSS feed shows 20 posts for example, but I want to include a certain category no matter how old the post is (for example, my 'featured' post category), and also just get 1 latest post from this category.

I've been trying to look for plugins, but I'm not exactly sure what it would be called. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[WP RSS Aggregator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-aggregator/)**  plugin, it has many options that i think it will help you for example : 
 -Set the name of the feed source
 -Select number of posts per feed you want to show and store
and more.